# X-cart 4.6 products listing path in admin

Tags: php, e-commerce, x-cart

I am very new in xcart and i am working in admin section and i want to add more column on product listing page but i could not find the path.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

The template is 
skin/common_files/main/products.tpl

There are 2 ways to find it

1) Using grep by a word from the page

```
aim-server[~/www/xcart_4_6_x]$ grep -r 'Quantity in stock' sql             
sql/xcart_language_US.sql:INSERT INTO xcart_languages VALUES ('en','lbl_in_stock','Quantity in stock','Labels');
sql/xcart_language_US.sql:INSERT INTO xcart_languages VALUES ('en','lbl_quantity_in_stock','Quantity in stock (items)','Labels');

aim-server[~/www/xcart_4_6_x]$ grep -rwl lbl_in_stock skin|grep -v customer
skin/common_files/main/quick_search.tpl
skin/common_files/main/products.tpl
skin/common_files/modules/Product_Options/product_variants.tpl
skin/common_files/provider/main/inv_update.tpl
```

2) Using Webmaster mode
https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Using_Webmaster_mode

Comment: Hello, glad to hear it, have you accepted my answer?